# How does this code only print out the initials of a string?

Tags: python

This is the function:

```py
def initials(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    result = ""
    for word in words:
        result += word[0]
    return result.upper()
```

This is an exercise on my online course. The objective is to return the first initials of a string capitalized. For example, initials ("Universal Serial Bus") should return "USB".

Comment: Is there a specific part of this code you don't understand? Do you know what `phase.split()` does? Do you know what for loops are? Do you know what `word[0]` does?

Comment: Honestly, I would advise going back to a basic tutorial. Trying to learn snippet by snippet without (apparently) knowing the very basics of the language will be a very bumpy road for you.

Comment: simply use `print()` to display values in variables in different places and moments. ie inside loop you could use `print(word, word[0], result)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
def initials(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    result = ""
    for word in words:
        result += word[0]
    return result.upper()
```

This:

1. Splits the phrase at every space (`" "`), with `phrase.split()`. `.split()` returns a list which is assigned to `words`
2. Iterates through the list `words` and adds the first letter of each word (`word[0]`) to the result variable.
3. Returns `result` converted to uppercase (`result.upper()`)

Answer (score 0):

`phrase` is a `str` type object.

`str` objects can have functions applied to them through their methods.  `split` is a function that returns a list containing multiple `str` objects.  This is stored in `words`

the `for word in words` takes each element of `words` and puts it in the variable `word` for each iteration of the loop.

The += function adds the first letter of word to `result` by accessing the first character of the `str` by using the `[0]` index of `word`.

Then the `upper` function is applied to the result.

I hope this clears it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def initials(phrase):
   words = phrase.split()
   result = ""
   for word in words:
      result += word[0].upper()
      return result
```

`print(ShortName("Active Teens Taking Initiative To Understand Driving Experiences"))`

## Should be: ATTITUDE

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the original question which is about how the provided code works and not an alternate solution to provide the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def initials(phrase):
    words =phrase.split()
    result=""+""
    for word in words:
        result += word[0].upper()
    return result
 
print(initials("Universal Serial Bus")) # Should be: USB
print(initials("local area network")) # Should be: LAN
print(initials("Operating system")) # Should be: OS
```

Here is output:

```
USB
LAN
OS
```

This:
Splits the phrase at every space (" "+" ") and concatenate next one first letter,with `phrase.split()` returns a list which is assigned to words Iterates through the list words and adds the first letter of each word (`word[0]`) to the result variable.
Returns result converted to uppercase (`result.upper()`)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

strong text

```
def initials(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    result = ""
    for word in words:
        result += word[0].uppper()
    return result
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).